# Swift HTTP Post Request fail to work

Tags: ios, swift, http

When the button is click, the testt function will first open the camera to get the scanned result. Then it will send a http post request to the url with the scanned result. The issue is now the camera can be open but the http post request is not working.

```
   @IBAction func testt(_ sender: Any) {

    guard checkScanPermissions() else { return }

    readerVC.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    readerVC.delegate                = self

    readerVC.completionBlock = { (result: QRCodeReaderResult?) in
        if let result = result {
            print("Completion with result: \(result.value) of type \(result.metadataType)")

        }
    }

    present(readerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

func reader5(_ reader: QRCodeReaderViewController, didScanResult result: QRCodeReaderResult){
    reader.stopScanning()

    dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
```

> POST REQUEST start

```
         let myUrl5 = URL(string: "http://ptsv2.com/t/jhil6-1522989475/post");

        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl5!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

        let postString = "test=" + result.value

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let data = data {
                let string = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                print(string) //

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.outlet4.text = string


                }   
            }

        }
        task.resume()

        //end of POST REQUES
    }

}


}
```

Comment: When you say that httpPost is not working - What issue are you facing ?

Comment: When i try to inspect http request using request bin, nothing is post

Comment: Put a breakpoint on if error != nil. Check if that is called

Comment: as @Nitish Pointed out, you should put a breadpoint at line [if error != nil]. Add break point by clicking on line numbers shown on left of editor

Comment: You can try Out [Upload Image using Multipart](https://gist.github.com/AshvinGudaliya/9a458de96c4efda4286491c4d2c0ce24)

Answer (score 0):

You will add below line in info.plist file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `let postString = "test=" + result.value` is making the blunder. Rather put it like `let postString = "test=\(result.value)"`. This should work.